# Set environment variable from credstash on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, credstash

I'm having some issues with Elastic Beanstalk environment variables which I want to set from credstash.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: SECRET_KEY_BASE
    value: $(credstash --region eu-west-1 -t credstash get test.secret_key_base)
```

I have specified that credstash should be installed from Python:

```
packages:
  python:
    credstash: []
```

However, when I deploy asset precompilation fails (`rake assets:precompile`).

The EB health page shows that application deployment failed.

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars: line 5: credstash: command not found
...
+ su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' webapp
`/home/webapp` is not a directory.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/webapp' as your home directory temporarily.
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: `secret_key_base` for production environment must be a type of String`
```

`secret_key_base` is set to `ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']` in `secrets.yml`, so it should contain the value from credstash. However, due to the `credstash: command not found` output, I'm guessing credstash was not installed or is not on the path for some reason.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to set `RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION` to `true`. This will skip the `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh` hook, which runs before credstash is installed.

Instead I included this in a `.config` file:

```
container_commands:
  01_assets_compile:
    command: bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will precompile the assets on each container, when credstash will be installed.